# Java 8 Streams, example that not compile

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

My question is short, why does it not compile?

```
final ArrayList <Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem occurs in `Collectors.toList()` part.

Comment: Why declared as ArrayList? It is good practice to declare interface instead of implementation if you don't really need it.

Comment: i have found the example in web and wondered why is that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collectors.toList()` returns some `List` implementation that doesn't have to be `ArrayList`, and probably isn't.

Try

```
final List <Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
                                     .boxed()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use `collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` if you specifically need an `ArrayList`.

```
final ArrayList <Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
                                          .boxed()
                                          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```